# How to hide element in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created html tables which has 2 rows, I would like to second rows until it will be clicked.

So my desired result is like this. This is `initial appearence`

[image]

And when I click cells `3`, this cells `want to be like this`.

[image]

When I tried below works,I couldn't hide `2nd row`, If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $("tr .color").removeClass("aqua");
    index = $("td").index(this);
    $("tr .color").slice(index+1, index + 4).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('aqua');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean after click it should hide the 2nd row after a small delay?

Comment: I would like to show 2nd row only when I click each cells. therefore I would like to hide them in initial state.

Comment: Why are some cells blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hide by default the second row, then add a class (e.g. `show`) on that row on the click event

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $("tr .color").removeClass("aqua");
    index = $("td").index(this);
    $("tr .color").slice(index+1, index + 4).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('aqua');
    }).parent().addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(2):not([class]) {
  display: none;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector and also hide the 2nd row by default using css `:nth-child` like:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $("table tr:eq(1)").show();
    $("tr .color").removeClass("aqua");
    index = $("td").index(this);
    $("tr .color").slice(index + 1, index + 4).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('aqua');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;  
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
    <td class="color"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```